# Mixing c++ and assembly language

Tags: c++, assembly, matrix-multiplication

I'm trying to matrix multiplication with 2d "int" arrays. I ask the users to insert the matrix via c++. Then, I use that data to do matrix multiplication in assembly. I got a runtime error when I tried moving an element of my "int" array into the 'ax' register. I'm not sure what's wrong.

```
void Matrix::Calculate()
{
signed short i =0, j=0, k=0 ;

__asm{

    xor eax,eax
    xor ebx,ebx
    xor edx,edx

    mov ecx, 3

    L1:
        push ecx
        mov ecx, 3
    L2 :
        push ecx
        mov ecx, 3
    L3 :
        mov ax, p[i][k]             //runtime error 
        mov bx, q[k][j]
        imul bx
        add r[i][j], bx     

        inc k
        loop L3

        pop ecx
        inc j
        loop L2

        pop ecx
        inc k
        loop L1
};

}
```

Comment: Are you sure that using an `__asm{}` block here is a good idea in the first place? I am not.

Comment: are you trying to access class members from asm? That's unlikely to work.

Comment: You cannot use pointers like that in x86 assembly: `mov ax, p[i][k]`. You have to calculate the address manually and then use one of the available [x86 Addressing Modes](https://sw0rdm4n.wordpress.com/2014/09/11/classic-knowledge-on-x86-addressing-modes/).

Comment: it's practice for mixing them. You can't access class members from asm?

Comment: What was the runtime error? Have you looked at the final assembly (or disassembled the executable) to see what the compiler did to your code? Did you try stepping through the code instruction-by-instruction in your debugger?

Comment: A class member will be an offset from "this" is asm. It's possible to load it's address into a register, then add offsets based on i and k, but depends on which compiler you use.

Comment: How did `p[i][k] ` even compile?  That's three C++ variables in one operand, and in MSVC syntax they will always be in memory, not registers.  I don't see how this could have compiled, yet you claim that you got a *runtime* error.  And BTW, why are you using 16-bit types for your counters?  And why would you use the slow `loop` instruction?  This looks like you were used to 8086, not modern x86 in 32-bit mode.

Comment: IMHO, first write the routine in C++.  Print out an assembly listing.  Use the assembly listing to create a separate assembly language file.  Adjust the assembly language file as you see fit.  This will help you get the correct calling conventions for the assembly language.

Comment: What Thomas suggested can be achieved with e.g. `g++ -S`. This makes GCC transpile to ASM instead of generating object code.